# Toggle hide and show

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tried everything to get it to toggle show and hide but every time I add hide in the function, it stops working or I can get hide to work flawlessly while show doesn't work at all. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<div class="ShowHideClicker clear" >
  <img src="something.gif"></div> <div class="ShowHideList"> 
  <div class="ui-widget" id="SearchBar"> 
    <label for="tags">Search:</label> 
    <input id="tags">
    <button class='clear' id="ClearButton"> Clear</button> 
  </div> 
  <div id="Result"></div> 
</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
     $('.ShowHideList').hide();
     $('.ShowHideClicker').click(function(){
          $(this).next().show('drop', {direction: 'left'}, 1000);
     });
});
```

Comment: Do you give html code?

Comment: @Sathiyaraj sorry about that, it is updated

Comment: You have a close span `</span>` with no matching open tag

Comment: @JRulle you are right I do, let me fix that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using the `.toggle()` this way: **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/LR45B/)** and make sure you have included jQuery and jQuery UI in your header (["drop" is a jQuery UI feature](http://api.jqueryui.com/drop-effect/))

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.ShowHideClicker').click(function(){
    $('.ShowHideList').toggle('drop', 1000);
  });
});
```

CSS:

```
.ShowHideList { display: none; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the simple solution with toggleClass:

```
$('.ShowHideClicker').on('click', function(){
    $(this).next().toggleClass('hidden');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LcYLY/